# Move solution in Source Control

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a project under source control in Visual Studio 2012 using TFS2010. When I added this project, the solution was not added in the correct file folder location. I want to move the solution, but every time I try to do it within the Source Control Explorer I encounter an error: "The project file 'path/to/project.csproj' has been moved, renamed, or is not on your computer." What is causing this error? What is the proper way to move the solution to where I want it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the solution file in TFS (this is more relevant if you have history you want to maintain)
Open the solution, it will complain that it can't load your projects, either edit the path to the project in the properties window, or remove each project and then re-add it. Check-in your changes

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .suo file and try once. Has helped me in the past. This file is usually hidden. Restart VS after deleting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the solution file has relative paths to the project files.  I usually do any moving around when I first create the solution (before there are projects in it).  However, in your case I would just use Source Control Explorer to move the solution, then edit the .sln file in a text editor and fix up the relative paths to the proj files.